# setting css class for dynamically generated checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a series of checkboxes that I'm adding to a panel programmatically. I set the CssClass property but instead of setting the CSS class of the control it just wraps it in a span with that CSS class. Is there a way to make it give the checkbox the class? I need the class on the actual checkbox because in javascript I'm selecting by class.

Here's my code:

```
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
        checkbox.Text = checkboxText;
        checkbox.ID = checkboxID;
        checkbox.CssClass = "chkRoles";
        pnlMandatoryRoles.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        pnlMandatoryRoles.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
```

Comment: try this `checkbox.InputAttributes["class"] = "chkRoles"` **instead of** `checkbox.CssClass = "chkRoles"`

Comment: Make this an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
checkbox.CssClass = "chkRoles"
```

With:

```
checkbox.InputAttributes["class"] = "chkRoles"
```

Answer (score 3):

Ues Like below

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
checkbox.Text = "checkboxText";
checkbox.ID = "checkboxID";
checkbox.InputAttributes["class"] ="chkRoles";
pnlMandatoryRoles.Controls.Add(checkbox);pnlMandatoryRoles.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
```